# How do I format these two complex cron statements?

Tags: cron

I need two very specific cron statements:

1. A cron entry that would run on the 2nd Monday of each month every 4 hours beginning at 02:00 and execute the file /opt/bin/cleanup.sh
2. A cron entry that would run at 18:15 on the 3rd day of every month ending in an "r" that executes /opt/bin/verrrrrrrry.sh

I've already tried various cron testers:

[cron checker](http://cronchecker.net/),[cron tester](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php),and [cron translator](https://crontranslator.appspot.com/)

however none of them seem to be able to handle advanced cron expressions(or I do not know how to format the correct expression) as stated on

[the cron trigger tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) and
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression)

How can I check my cron statements? I obviously cannot wait for the actual event to pass so that the daemon may execute them.

Is there a good cron tester which supports advanced expressions? Or how to make the cron daemon parse the expression, or how to code these expressions?

What I have so far for these statements is:

1. `0 2 * * 0#2 /opt/bin/cleanup.sh`
2. `15 18 3 * * /opt/bin/verrrrrrrry.sh`

But of course these are not correct.

For #1, I do not know how to specify the '2nd Monday', nor 'every 4 hours', while still beginning at 02:00.

For #2, I have no idea how to only specify months ending in an 'r' except by manually coding them in. Nor do I know how to specify the 3rd day.

Comment: "Specify months ending in an 'r'"... You mean months whose names have "r" as their last letter O_o? So, in English, September to December? That's a peculiar specification.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have something execute only on the second Monday of a month the day of week value needs to be 1 and the day of month value has to be 8-14, the hour has to be 2,6,10,14,18,22 and the minute 0. However as dhag correctly commented and provided a solution for, when you specify both the day of week and the day of month (i.e. not as `*`), the program is executed when either matches. Therefore you have to test explicitly for either one, and the day of week is easier:

```
 0 2,6,10,14,18,22 8-14 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 1 && /opt/bin/cleanup.sh
```

The final 1 determines the Monday and the range of day of month (8-14) picks it only when it is the second Monday.

The third day of every month ending in an "r" at 18:15:

```
 15 18 3 september,october,november,december * /opt/bin/verrrrrrrry.sh
```

(at least on Vixie cron you can use the names of the months. If yours does not support that you can replace that with `9-12`)

Comment: When both day and day-of-week are specified, they are OR-ed together: your first job runs every Monday and on days 8-14. I suggest testing for Mondays within the command, perhaps `0 2 8-14 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 1 && /opt/bin/cleanup.sh`. (This misses the other requirement "every four hours starting at 2", which you got right.)

Comment: @dhag you are right, it says so in the man pages.

Answer (score 2):

The format is
minute / hour / day of month / month / day of week

So that would make

`0 4 9-15 * 2 /opt/bin/cleanup.sh` and

`15 18 3 8-14 * /opt/bin/verrrrrrrry.sh`

Comment: If the 1st is a Monday, then the second Monday is the 8th of the month.

Comment: You're right, corrected.

Comment: And that only runs it at 4 am, not a 2 am, 6am, etc

Comment: As the question doesn't specify until when it's to be run every 4h, I omitted this, as it can be easily adapted.

Answer (score 1):

**A cron entry that would run on the 2nd Monday of each month every 4 hours beginning at 02:00**

```
00 02/4 8-14 * * [ `date +\%u` = 1 ] && /opt/bin/cleanup.sh
```

- `http://crontab.guru/#00_02/4_8-14_*_1`

**A cron entry that would run at 18:15 on the 3rd day of every month ending in an "r"**

```
15 18 3 9-12 * /opt/bin/verrrrrrrry.sh
```

- `http://crontab.guru/#15_18_3_9-12_*`

Comment: @Archemar, I love downvotes (ofcourse with reasons specified), corrected it according to http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crontab&sektion=5, which is same what @ Anthon suggested